# Jquery change src of audio and play on keydown

Tags: jquery, audio, src, keydown

I have the following code that's working except for case 78 (letter N).  When this key is pressed the audio starts to play but then stops.  The other keys play the new audio file. I think the problem might have something to do with the keydown being pressed when the src file is being changed.  Here's a working fiddle:  [keysounds](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/zgpxrfhg/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
   <script 
      type        = "text/javascript" 
      src         = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity   = "sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin = "anonymous">
   </script>
   <script>
   /*global $ */
      $(function() {
         var playing;
         $(document).on("keydown", function(key) {
           playing = undefined;
           switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
              case 68:
                 playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
                 break;
              case 78:
                 playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
                 $("#sound0").attr("src",'sound2.mp3');
                 break;
              case 79:
                 playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
                 break;
              case 83:
                 playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
                 break;
              case 85:
                 playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
                 break;     
           };

           if(playing){
              playing.play();
           }

         }).on("keyup", function() {
            if(playing){
               playing.pause();
               playing.currentTime=0;
              playing = undefined;
            }
         });
      }); 
   </script>
   <style>
       div{
           text-align:center;
           margin-top:50%;
       }
       span{
           border-style:double;
           margin:.4%;
       }
   </style>
   <title>Keys</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>S</span>
        <span>O</span>
        <span>U</span>
        <span>N</span>
        <span>D</span>
        <span>S</span>
    </div>
    <audio  id="sound0" src="sound0.wav" ></audio>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the `src` attribute AFTER having it getted in the `playing` variable.

It should work if you just inverse two lines, like this:

```
case 78:
   $("#sound0").attr("src",'sound2.mp3');
   playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
   break;
```

You should also reset the original audio source for next iterations.

---

**EDIT**

The use of a "flag" to determine if the key is held avoids the `keydown` event to trigger your script too often... and to let the music play.

```
/*global $ */
$(function() {
  var playing;
  var keyHeld=false;        // Flag!

  $(document).on("keydown", function(key) {
    if(!keyHeld){
      keyHeld=true;

      // Reset to original sound
      $("#sound0").attr("src",'http://www.sailwbob.com/sound0.wav');


      switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        case 68:
          playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
          break;
        case 78:
          $("#sound0").attr("src",'http://www.sailwbob.com/sound2.mp3');
          playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
          break;
        case 79:
          playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
          break;
        case 83:
          playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
          break;
        case 85:
          playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
          break;
        default:
          $("#sound0").attr("src",'');          // On other key, Play nothing!
          playing = $("#sound0").get(0);
                                    };

      if($("#sound0").attr("src")!=""){
        playing.play();
      }
    }
  }).on("keyup", function() {
    if(playing){
      playing.pause();
      playing.currentTime=0;
      keyHeld=false;
    }
  });
});
```

Here is your [**Fiddle updated**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/Ln73vv4p/)

Comment: no, that doesn't work.  the sound cuts out after playing one note

Comment: That is because of your keyup handler... I removed it... Works fine now

Comment: no, it doesn't work at all.  you need the keyup event. the sound should only play when the key is held down

Comment: Do you want the music played ON HOLD of the key? mmm okay hold on.

Comment: I just edited again, because music was playing on every keys... This is fixed.

Comment: awesome, I would have never figured that out. thanks.

Comment: It was a pleasure ;)

Comment: can you explain why we don't need the keyhold flag when we are not changing the src for the audio file?

Comment: The `keyHeld` on the first `keydown` event when it is false. Then we check for which key. So, the flag changes everytime you hit a key... To true ON FIRST `keydown` and to false on `keyup`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139426/discussion-between-dcr-and-louys-patrice-bessette).